# IIS 7.5 not able to server Javascript file, throws 500 error.

Tags: iis-7.5, javascript

I have a site sitting on IIS 7.5. There are numerous JavaScript files that are being served from a scripts folder. Most of those files are served properly but there is one file that causes IIS to throw a 500 error.

On examining that JavaScript file I can see a warning about the file being from an untrusted source. None of the other JavaScript files show this warning. The file was copied along with the other files from our deployment/QA server where everything worked correctly.

Why is this single file marked as UnTrusted but other files are not? How can I remove that flag so that the file will be served as required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the file in Windows Explorer, and open its properties, on the `General` tab there is an `Unblock` button. Click that.

On newer Windows versions you can also use PowerShell:

```
Unblock-File myfile.js
```

I am not sure whether this is available on Server 2008 R2